# What is "game state?"

Tags: game-design, terminology

The terminology "game state" is a bit vague to me. Could anybody clarify what is included in the game state, please?

Is it a state of all the variables and objects within the game at particular moment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> An Introduction: Just what in the
>   world is state?
>
> Game state can be used to mean a
>   variety of things and you'll find it
>   used in many different ways in the
>   game industry. In this case I'm using
>   "game state" to provide a description
>   of an object at a given point in time
>   in a game. Clear as mud to you now?
>   Don't worry, I'll try to describe it
>   in a different way, one as a geek like
>   me you might identify with a little
>   better.
>
> Comic books. When buying used comic
>   books, they often say what "state" or
>   condition the comic book is in. The
>   current state of the comic book gives
>   you some indication of how the comic
>   book is going to look when you
>   purchase it. Mint, Fine and Poor all
>   give an image in your mind of just how
>   battered  or worn the comic book is.
>
> The same is true for objects in your
>   game. By defining the various valid
>   states for your objects, your game
>   will know just what to do when it is
>   in that state. And just like the comic
>   book industry has defined the various
>   valid states for comic books, you as
>   the governing board for your game must
>   define valid states for your objects
>   and just exactly how the game should
>   respond when those objects are in any
>   given state.

Since this Game State introduction has a very nice way to explain it, i quoted it and you can find the complete article at http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thestateofthings/thestateofthings.shtml

Comment: Thank you for this deailed and easy to understand explanation. To summarize, if I want to save a game play, I will simply gather the game state (states of all the relevant objects) and save them one by one.

Comment: Have a look at the following question for more alternative definitions: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/alternative-to-game-state-system

Comment: The analogy of a comic book is slightly misleading given that is describing the state of quality, and not state in general.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently looking this subject up myself. This link gives great advice to implement a simple game stack/ state.  http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/articles/game-design-articles/how-to-build-a-jrpg-a-primer-for-game-developers/#state